# Build ICU for 64 bit iOS

Tags: iphone, 64-bit, simulator, icu

I'm trying to move my app to 64 bit arm processors (and 64 bit simulator), and for that I need to recompile the ICU library (49).

After three days I reached the point where the library compiles fine, and the script I'm using puts together various architectures into one (snippet):

```
# ...

#x86_64
DEVROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer
SDKROOT=$DEVROOT/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk
SYSROOT=$SDKROOT

export CFLAGS="-I$SDKROOT/usr/include/ -I./include/ $ICU_FLAGS -arch x86_64 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot $SDKROOT -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -O3 -DU_HAVE_GCC_ATOMICS=0"
export CXXFLAGS="$CFLAGS"
export CC="$TOOLCHAINSROOT/usr/bin/clang"
export CXX="$TOOLCHAINSROOT/usr/bin/clang++"
export LDFLAGS="-L$SDKROOT/usr/lib/ -isysroot $SDKROOT -Wl,-dead_strip  -miphoneos-version-min=7.0"

mkdir -p $BUILDDIR/iosbuild/x86_64
cd $BUILDDIR/iosbuild/x86_64
gnumake clean
sh $ICU_PATH/source/configure --host=arm-apple-darwin --enable-static --disable-shared -with-cross-build=$BUILDDIR/hostbuild --prefix=$BUILDDIR/iosbuild/x86_64 --with-data-packaging=library
gnumake
gnumake clean install

# ...


#x86_64
mkdir -p ${BUILDDIR}/iosbuild/x86_64/lib/libicudata
cd ${BUILDDIR}/iosbuild/x86_64/lib/libicudata
ar -x "${BUILDDIR}/iosbuild/x86_64/lib/libicudata.a"

mkdir -p ${BUILDDIR}/iosbuild/x86_64/lib/libicui18n
cd ${BUILDDIR}/iosbuild/x86_64/lib/libicui18n
ar -x "${BUILDDIR}/iosbuild/x86_64/lib/libicui18n.a"

mkdir -p ${BUILDDIR}/iosbuild/x86_64/lib/libicuio
cd ${BUILDDIR}/iosbuild/x86_64/lib/libicuio
ar -x "${BUILDDIR}/iosbuild/x86_64/lib/libicuio.a"

mkdir -p ${BUILDDIR}/iosbuild/x86_64/lib/libicule
cd ${BUILDDIR}/iosbuild/x86_64/lib/libicule
ar -x "${BUILDDIR}/iosbuild/x86_64/lib/libicule.a"

mkdir -p ${BUILDDIR}/iosbuild/x86_64/lib/libiculx
cd ${BUILDDIR}/iosbuild/x86_64/lib/libiculx
ar -x "${BUILDDIR}/iosbuild/x86_64/lib/libiculx.a"

mkdir -p ${BUILDDIR}/iosbuild/x86_64/lib/libicutest
cd ${BUILDDIR}/iosbuild/x86_64/lib/libicutest
ar -x "${BUILDDIR}/iosbuild/x86_64/lib/libicutest.a"

mkdir -p ${BUILDDIR}/iosbuild/x86_64/lib/libicutu
cd ${BUILDDIR}/iosbuild/x86_64/lib/libicutu
ar -x "${BUILDDIR}/iosbuild/x86_64/lib/libicutu.a"

mkdir -p ${BUILDDIR}/iosbuild/x86_64/lib/libicuuc
cd ${BUILDDIR}/iosbuild/x86_64/lib/libicuuc
ar -x "${BUILDDIR}/iosbuild/x86_64/lib/libicuuc.a"

ar -qc ${BUILDDIR}/iosbuild/x86_64/lib/libcombinedicu.a ${BUILDDIR}/iosbuild/x86_64/lib/libicudata/*.o ${BUILDDIR}/iosbuild/x86_64/lib/libicudata/*.ao ${BUILDDIR}/iosbuild/x86_64/lib/libicuuc/*.ao ${BUILDDIR}/iosbuild/x86_64/lib/libicui18n/*.ao ${BUILDDIR}/iosbuild/x86_64/lib/libicuio/*.ao ${BUILDDIR}/iosbuild/x86_64/lib/libicule/*.ao ${BUILDDIR}/iosbuild/x86_64/lib/libiculx/*.ao ${BUILDDIR}/iosbuild/x86_64/lib/libicutest/*.ao ${BUILDDIR}/iosbuild/x86_64/lib/libicutu/*.ao ${BUILDDIR}/iosbuild/x86_64/lib/libicuuc/*.ao

# ...

#put them together
lipo -create -arch x86_64 "${BUILDDIR}/iosbuild/x86_64/lib/libcombinedicu.a"
             -arch i386 "${BUILDDIR}/iosbuild/i386/lib/libcombinedicu.a" 
                        "${BUILDDIR}/iosbuild/arm64/lib/libcombinedicu.a" 
                        "${BUILDDIR}/iosbuild/armv7s/lib/libcombinedicu.a"
             -arch armv7 "${BUILDDIR}/iosbuild/armv7/lib/libcombinedicu.a"
             -o "$FRAMEWORK_DIR/Versions/Current/$FRAMEWORK_NAME"
```

The problem is, when I'm compiling the app from XCode (for the 64 bit simulator), I get the following errors regarding the built ICU framework:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F"/Users/gliptak/ac/m-220/Sources/VBExplorer/BIMxPro/../BIMxEngine/extern/icu"'

duplicate symbol _OSAtomicIncrement32 in:
/Users/gliptak/ac/m-220/Sources/VBExplorer/BIMxEngine/extern/icu/ICU.framework/ICU(unistr.ao)
/Users/gliptak/ac/m-220/Sources/VBExplorer/BIMxEngine/extern/icu/ICU.framework/ICU(mutex.ao)

duplicate symbol _OSAtomicIncrement32Barrier in:
/Users/gliptak/ac/m-220/Sources/VBExplorer/BIMxEngine/extern/icu/ICU.framework/ICU(unistr.ao)
/Users/gliptak/ac/m-220/Sources/VBExplorer/BIMxEngine/extern/icu/ICU.framework/ICU(mutex.ao)

duplicate symbol _OSAtomicDecrement32 in:
/Users/gliptak/ac/m-220/Sources/VBExplorer/BIMxEngine/extern/icu/ICU.framework/ICU(unistr.ao)
/Users/gliptak/ac/m-220/Sources/VBExplorer/BIMxEngine/extern/icu/ICU.framework/ICU(mutex.ao)

duplicate symbol _OSAtomicDecrement32Barrier in:
/Users/gliptak/ac/m-220/Sources/VBExplorer/BIMxEngine/extern/icu/ICU.framework/ICU(unistr.ao)
/Users/gliptak/ac/m-220/Sources/VBExplorer/BIMxEngine/extern/icu/ICU.framework/ICU(mutex.ao)

...

ld: 64 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

<strike>As far as I can tell the mentioned functions are declared in system headers, and are not inline, so how can this error exist?</strike>

Do you have any ideas what I might do wrong?

**UPDATE:** indeed, those functions are static inline, so they cause the problem. So the question is now how do I avoid duplication?

**UPDATE:** tried the -std=gnu89 flag for the C compiler, no effect...

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution [here](http://www.boevewebdevelopment.nl/blog/post/compile-php-on-os-x-mavericks) (confirmed working building on/for Mavericks). Could also be resolved using SVN trunk of icu4c, since that uses C++11 barriers instead.

Comment: I ended up using libicucore.dylib provided by the ios sdk (and NSString for the missing functionality).